# Kicking Discord Users Through Bot in CS

Tags: c#, discord, discord.net

I'm creating a discord bot, and I'm struggling to figure out how to kick a user. I can't find code or documentation on this. Here's the code

```
private void MuteUserCommand()
    {
        commands.CreateCommand("stfu")
            .Parameter("PersonToKick", ParameterType.Required)
            .Do(async (e) =>
            {
                string persontomute = e.GetArg("PersonToKick");
                if (e.User.ServerPermissions.MuteMembers == false)
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendMessage("Yoo cahnot tells " + persontomute + " to shut up, iz not enuff poweh!");
                }
                else
                {
                    await e.Channel.SendMessage("Shut up " + persontomute + "!");
                    //How do I kick persontomute here?
                }
            });
    }
```

Update: I'm using Discord.NET 0.9.6

Comment: What functions are available under `e.Channel`?

Comment: FindUsers is one of the functions, but I have no idea how to use it.

Comment: Please update your original post and tell us what Discord .NET Framework you are using

Comment: Done and dusted. Thanks for the suggestion

Comment: https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net/blob/master/src/Discord.Net/Models/Server.cs look through the above file for `GetUser` and `FindUsers`

Answer (score 2):

This is the command I use to kick people, checking for the correct permissions etc. (Make sure the bot has kick permissions itself ofcourse)

```
_client.GetService<CommandService>().CreateGroup("user", cgb =>
        {
            cgb.CreateCommand("kick")
                .Description("Kick a user from the Server.")
                .Parameter("User", ParameterType.Required)
                .AddCheck((command, user, channel) => !paused)
                .Do(async e =>
                {
                    try
                    {
                        if (e.User.ServerPermissions.KickMembers)
                        {
                            User user = null;
                            try
                            {
                                // try to find the user
                                user = e.Server.FindUsers(e.GetArg("User")).First();
                            }
                            catch (InvalidOperationException)
                            {
                                await e.Channel.SendMessage($"Couldn't kick user {e.GetArg("User")} (not found).");
                                return;
                            }
                            // double safety check
                            if (user == null) await e.Channel.SendMessage($"Couldn't kick user {e.GetArg("User")} (not found).");
                            await user.Kick();
                            await e.Channel.SendMessage($"{user.Name} was kicked from the server!");
                        }
                        else
                        {
                            await e.Channel.SendMessage($"{e.User.Name} you don't have the permission to kick.");
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        // needs a better error handling haven't changed it since i tested it xD
                        await e.Channel.SendMessage(ex.Message);
                    }
                });
```

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be using [Discord.Net](https://github.com/RogueException/Discord.Net). You need to get the user from the server and then kick them, as explaned in the [documentation](http://rtd.discord.foxbot.me/en/legacy/features/user-management.html#kicking).
EDIT: my bad, I took this snippet from a friend's bot and forgot it used a custom extension. I added a "vanilla" way, taken **[straight from the sample bot](https://github.com/RogueException/DiscordBot/blob/master/src/DiscordBot/Modules/Admin/AdminModule.cs)**.

```
var user = await _client.FindUser(e, e.Args[0], e.Args[1]); //args[0]would be the username, args[1] would be the discriminator (the random number that follows the discord id)
if (user == null) return;    
await user.Kick();
```

Old

```
string err;
User user = e.Server.Users.FindUser(persontomute, out err);
if(user != null) 
{
   await user.Kick();
   await e.Channel.SendMessage("Shut up " + persontomute + "!");
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! You saved my from loads of agony. I'll implement this right away

Comment: Np, just accept the answer. For future reference, here's a sample bot that show off most of the api: https://github.com/RogueException/DiscordBot

Comment: It's telling me that the second argument cannot except the out keyword.

Comment: Here's what to do since fhlamarche has provided you with a snippet of code to set you on the right path. Go and read the documentation & unit tests of the github repository he linked and then see what you can come up with. You said the documentation is hard to find but I found it in seconds on Google's third result.

Comment: I don't think you understand my problem. I found this documentation, https://github.com/RogueException/DiscordBot/blob/master/src/DiscordBot/Extensions.cs     and it uses the FindUser command, but I don't understand what the second parameter is. I looked for other sources but none of them explain what it's supposed to be. Visual studio is telling me it's supposed to be a bool that determines if it needs to be case specific or not, but it doesn't want to take a bool.